# joining 3 tables using month and year criteria

Tags: sql

I wanted to join three tables.

There are two conditions for joining the tables,[project number] and [current month]-a date field.By specifying the month and year together with the project number i want to get the result.

I used this code but when it gets to the second join statement it raises an error->Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression ''.

I omitted the second join statement to test the first join but the result i get is 4x the actual record.If i have like 4 record in each table to be joined i get 64 records.

Any modifications on my code will be really appreciated.Also I'm using temporary table.

```
     INSERT INTO patempTable 
               SELECT 
                      pr.[project number], 
                      pr.[employee number], 
                      pr.[current month], 
                      pr.[net pay], 
                      al.[net allowance], 
                      pd.[net] 
               FROM 
                      [pay_roll] pr 
               INNER JOIN [allowance] al ON pr.[project number] = al.[project number]
                     AND MONTH(pr.[current month])=MONTH(al.[current month]) 
                     AND YEAR(pr.[current month])=YEAR(al.[current month]) 
               JOIN [per_diem_accomodation] pd ON pr.[project number]=pd.[project number] 
                    AND MONTH(pr.[current month])= MONTH(pd.[current month])
                    AND YEAR(pr.[current month])=YEAR(pd.[current month]) 
               WHERE 
                    pr.[project number]='" & projcode & "' AND 
                    MONTH(pr.[current month])=" & monthnumber & " AND  
                    YEAR(pr.[current month])=" & period
```

Comment: Arrange the SQL code properly.It's almost non-readable :(

Comment: Why `JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` ? Why mixing month/year `YEAR(pr.[current month])` ? What is your RDBMS ? Can you give us ur table content ? Can you fill up a http://sqlfiddle.com/ for us ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Project Number and Current Month are not unique in your tables so you are getting a Cartesian product. Imagine this simple example:

```
Table1                  Table2

+------+------+         +------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 |         | Col1 | Col2 |
+------+------+         +------+------+
|  A   |  1   |         |  A   |  3   |
|  A   |  2   |         |  A   |  4   |
+------+------+         +------+------+
```

Then running this query:

```
SELECT  t1.Col1, t1.Col2, t1.Col3
FROM    Table1 AS t1
        INNER JOIN Table2 AS t2
            ON t1.Col1 = t2.Col1;
```

You will end up with:

```
+------+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col2 |
+------+------+------+
|  A   |  1   |  3   |
|  A   |  2   |  3   |
|  A   |  1   |  4   |
|  A   |  2   |  4   |
+------+------+------+
```

i.e. You get every possible combination of rows from the two tables, doubling the number of rows in the first table. You either need to summarise your tables in subqueries, i.e.

```
SELECT  t1.Col1, t1.Col2, t1.Col3
FROM    (   SELECT  Col1, SUM(Col2) AS Col2
            FROM    Table1 
            GROUP BY Col1 
        ) AS t1
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  Col1, SUM(Col2) AS Col2
            FROM    Table2 
            GROUP BY Col1 
        ) AS t2
            ON t1.Col1 = t2.Col1;

+------+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col2 |
+------+------+------+
|  A   |  3   |  7   |
+------+------+------+
```

Or you need to extend your join criteria to make it at least a 1-n relationship, rather than n-n.

I don't know what your data is, or what your expected outcome is, so I can't suggest anything further yet.

On an unrelated, but **very** important note, **[USE PARAMETERIZED QUERIES](http://bobby-tables.com/)**. [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) is a potential risk of concatenating variables to your SQL, however it is far from the only reason to use it. When you use parameterised queries you will be able to make use of cached query plans, meaning the SQL doesn't have to be compiled each time it is sent to the server, your parameters are also more strongly typed, reducing conversion errors or truncation, e.g. adding a date parameter will send a date to the server, a date is a date, it cannot be misconstrued by regional settings, whereas if you pass a date as a concatenated string, unless you use a culture invariant date setting there is a chance of getting a conversion error.